# Ruby changes multiple variables but they shouldn't change

Tags: ruby

When I try to shorten an array with `''` the output from all other variables is changing too

```
message = "bot.start"
seperator = message
command = seperator
command[0..3] = ''
message #=> "start"
```

The output should be `"bot.start"`. Ruby should have a problem separating variables from each other. What is wrong?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but usually use of `=` means that you're referring to the same object. If that's the case, `command = seperator` makes `command` *literally* the same object as `seperator`. You'll likely need to make a copy of `seperator` before assigning if you want them to act separately.

Comment: Why do you think "[t]he output should be `"bot.start"`?

Comment: By the way, your `message` is a string, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version Ruby, strings are mutable. That is, you can change an instance of a string.

In your example, `message`, `command` and `separator` are all different variables that point to the same string instance. When you do `[0..3] = ''`, you are changing the string that all the variables point to.

If you need to make distinct instances, use `dup` to copy the string:

```
command = seperator.dup
```

Alternatively, don't modify the string and use APIs that return a new instance of a string:

```
command = seperator[4..-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute line 4

`command[0..3] = ''`

You grabed `bot.` and changed to `bot.` => `''`

That's why it returns`''start` which is `start`

https://repl.it/repls/BlushingThoughtfulOrigin